# Is there another way to get a map of a map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My json looks like:

```
{
"cars": [
      {
        "id": 6,
        "boardId": 8,
        "sprintId": 6,
        "name": "Backlog",
        "sortOrder": 1,
        "createdAt": "2018-04-25T10:00:38.628845Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-04-25T10:00:38.628845Z",
        "carSet": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "createdAt": "2018-04-25T10:00:38.628845Z",
            "car": {
              "id": 1,
              "createdAt": "2018-04-25T10:00:38.628845Z",
            }
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "createdAt": "2018-04-25T10:00:38.628845Z",
            "car": {
              "id": 2,
              "createdAt": "2018-04-25T10:00:38.628845Z",
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

Previously I was doing this:

```
this.props.cars.map((car) => {

});
```

But now in my JSON I have another layer with **carSet**.

So do I have to do a map of a map or is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

Same way:

```
this.props.cars.map((car) => 
 car.carSet.map(carsetItem => 
    <SomeComponent key={carsetItem.id} {...carsetItem}/>)
);
```

Crutches can reduce your perfomance.

## Edit

If you use redux and use more of data, you can try to expand your data to partials, and play with [redux normalization](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape)

Comment: what is a crutch? curly brace?